# Docker: Which approach is better? WAR embedded in image or base image + war?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

Just started playing around with Docker. To deploy a war on tomcat there seem to be two approaches:

1. Create image with java + tomcat + war embedded in the image
2. Have a base image with java + tomcat and then "inject" the war into the base image (through host volume mount, for example)

Approach 1:

- Need to create one image for each build
- Completely bundled solution
- Due to the large image sizes, maintaining one image for each build and sharing the image for downstream deployment could become an issue

Approach 2:

- Keep a base image in docker hub
- Add war externally and run
- Smaller distributable size (only war), but additional step that the deployment team needs to 'know' the name of image to run

Which of these approaches is typically used in production?

Comment: There is no typically about it - both are used as well as the third option: neither since Docker is relatively young still. Its also pretty situational - approach 1 doesn't really work when you want to deploy multiple applications part of different projects to the same Tomcat instance for example. Your question basically boils down to "when do you embed the server in your application framework and when do you keep them isolated".

Comment: As @Gimby said it is not a standard way to do it. Personally I would choose the second approach, or may be having only the base image, and from there share the war with Docker volumes or injecting the war through a shell script run each time the container is created (having the possibility to pass some parameters to manage several wars). Anyway the implementation chosen should depend the purpose: If you want your docker images for development, choose something like the second approach. On the other hand you want the image for distributing, may be the first one would be more adequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to deploy your code onto a docker orchestration service such as Google Container Engine, Amazon Container Service etc then option 1 is normally the only feasible solution as you don't have access to the host. Option 1 is also more scalable on docker orchestration systems as you can create multiple instances of your service on various docker hosts.

However, I myself use option 2 for the reasons you have mentioned and because I manage scaling through auto-scaling groups using cloud formation which can provision instances with my war in the local store. Right now I don't think docker orchestration is mature enough for me to replace my external orchestration systems and if I have those systems setup then there is no point loosing the benefits of approach 2. However, when amazon allows us to connect ELBs directly to docker containers and makes a few more improvements I will seriously reconsider.

> Due to the large image sizes, maintaining one image for each build and sharing the image for downstream deployment could become an issue

FYI Docker uses a diff based file system so as long as you are only changing the war file your image storage should not be an issue.